# getElementById in loop doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm checking table cells using loop like this:

```
for (var h = i - 1; h < i + 2; h++) {
  for (var w = j - 1; w < j + 2; w++) {
    cell = document.getElementById('cell-' + (h).toString() + '-' + (w).toString());
    console.log(cell.classList);
  }
}
```

And I get 
**TypeError: cell is null**

But when I use numbers not variables getting elements by their IDs it works fine. For example:

```
for (var h = i - 1; h < i + 2; h++) {
  for (var w = j - 1; w < j + 2; w++) {
    cell = document.getElementById('cell-' + (1).toString() + '-' + (1).toString());
    console.log(cell.classList);
  }
}
```

What's wrong with this part of code? How do I iterate through cells using loop?

Comment: What is the initial values of `i` and `j` ?

Comment: `(h).toString()` and `(1).toString()` are pointless, you'll convert to a string just by doing `some_string + some_number`.

Comment: they are also in a loop  
`for (var i = 1; i < table.length - 1; i++) {

                for (var j = 1; j < table[0].length - 1; j++) {`

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut snap! What it might be worth doing is console.logging the strings you're passing to getElementById.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is here, but it isn't because you are using variables instead of number literals. It will be because you are using the wrong numbers. We can't see what numbers you are using (we don't know what most of your variables start at) or what numbers you should be using (we can't see your HTML). You should provide a real [mcve]. You should also `console.log()` `h` and `w` to see what element you are actually looking for.

Comment: There must some cell which does't exists. `console.log(h, w, cell)` and debug for which `h` and `w` cell is null.

Comment: @PraveenGupta yes, you were right. Sometimes the function tries to check a cell that doesn't exist. I was inattentive

Answer (score 2):

Try to use String Literals in you calculation.
No need to use `toString()` at all.

```js
function getCell(){
for(i=0;i <5; i++){
  var  cell = document.getElementById(`cell-${i}`);
  console.log(cell)
}
}
```

```html
<div id="cell-0"></div>
<div id="cell-1"></div>
<div id="cell-2"></div>
<div id="cell-3"></div>
<div id="cell-4"></div>

<button onclick="getCell()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the other solution, but if you're into your functional programming, you may or may not prefer to use something along the lines of this. I know there's already a valid answer, but with my solution, it's all functional.

I mean I'm not here to get into a debate about whether or not you **should** be using functional programming over procedural or whatever, I'm simply providing an alternative solution.

```js
/*
window.getCells = () => {
  // Get a HTMLCollection. 
  const cellCollection = document.querySelectorAll("[id*=cell]"); 

  // Convert to array so we can use map.
  const cellArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(cellCollection);

  // Now print each item.
  cellArray.map(i => console.log(i));  
};
*/

// Pretty much a one liner, used a return character to make it slightly more readable. 
window.getCells = () => Array.prototype.slice
  .call(document.querySelectorAll("[id*=cell]"))
  .map(i => console.log(i));
```

```html
<div id="cell-0"></div>
<div id="cell-1"></div>
<div id="cell-2"></div>
<div id="cell-3"></div>
<div id="cell-4"></div>

<button onclick="getCells()">Click Me</button>
```